# Redirection in Linux with dup2() and create() inside a loop

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am running the code below and I cannot redirect to a file. The file is made, but nothing is put into it. If I remove the last `dup2(saveout,1)` statement, I can create and write into the file, but I cannot get back to the terminal, which is important. As soon as I put the `dup2(saveout,1)` back in my code, the redirection stops working, but I can get back to the terminal. I do not understand why this is happening. I would like to redirect and go back into the terminal.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace std;

void printmessage() {
    printf("this is the message\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    int saveout;
    int fd;
    saveout = dup(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fd = creat("/home/carl/example.txt",O_CREAT|O_APPEND);
        dup2(fd, 1);
        close(fd);
        printf("Testing the message");
        printmessage();

       dup2(saveout,1);
       close(saveout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `dup2(saveout,1);` will fail because you closed `saveout`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a file rights issue, you should read the man pages of the functions you are using.

```
creat() takes as first argument the filename, and as second the file creation rights, not its opening mode.
```

The **creat()** functions is a simple open() call, with some particular flags, so that you'll just have to set up the rights.

if you want to open your file, and create it if he doesn't exists, use

```
open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0600) for example, or
creat(filename, 0600),
```

which is mostly its equivalent, but you wont be able to append text, as "creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC"

Answer (score 0):

[`printf` is buffered by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) (line-by-line for output to a tty, perhaps differently for output to something else). Before both your calls to `dup2(..., 1)`, you should flush with `fflush`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```